# i want to get the selected rows in magento table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

i want to get the Customer and Orders rows in magento table the list is given below.

> **Customer:**
>
> Email , Customer Group,Newsletter.Billing Address(First Name,Last
> Name,Company, Address 1 , Address 2 ,Country , State , City , Zip Code
> , Telephone).Shipping Address ( First Name , Last Name , Company ,
> Address 1 , Address 2 ,Country , State , City , Zip Code , Telephone
> ).
>
> **ORDERS:**
>
> ID , Order Date , Order Status , Order Products ( Name , SKU ) ,
> Product Price , Quantity , SubTotal Price , Discount Price ,
> Tax Price , Shipping Price , Total Price , Order Comments.Customer
> Name , Billing Address ( First Name , Last Name , Address 1 , Address
> 2 , Country , State , City , Zip Code , Telephone ) .Shipping Address
> ( First Name , Last Name , Company , Address 1 , Address 2 ,  Country
> , State , City , Zip Code , Telephone )

Any one help me.